# Get public posts of public group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have the app in development, where I want to show facebook group public posts ( https://www.facebook.com/Microsoft/ ). I'm not a group admin :) . When I tried to access posts by graph api, i've got the

> (#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token

error message.

And I cannot request access to "Pages Public Content" (cannot pass verification).

what permission can I request to read group public posts?

Comment: (Just FYI, what you linked to is a Facebook _page_, not a _group_. Those are two very different things.)

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook API works like this,
Development Mode: For development mode you can try to access data/posts from group which is associated with the account in which app created. So, that group and posts associated in that group can be accessible. You can try following link,

***https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/group/feed***

Live mode: In case of live mode you need to create a video of snapshot using your development mode functionality and get "Pages Public Content Access" permission approved. Then you can access the public post associated with public groups.